# 'Cucumber' symbol not recognized in runner class

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cucumber

When trying to run my cucumber test in android studio I am getting the error message in regards to my runner `class junit annotation @RunWith(Cucumber.class):`

> Error:(9, 10) error: cannot find symbol class Cucumber

I have the libraries that I need installed. Why am I getting this message?

Here is a screenshot of my modules build.gradle class.
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXx4a.png)

Comment: Your classpath is broken.

Please share how you include the Cucumber jars in your project.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg I added a screenshot of my modules build.gradle class through which i have added  my cucumber dependencies. Thank you for taking the time to respond.